# Write an Async method that will await a bool

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I would like to write a method that will `await` for a variable to be set to true.

Here is the psudo code.

```
bool IsSomethingLoading = false
SomeData TheData;

public async Task<SomeData> GetTheData()
{
   await IsSomethingLoading == true;
   return TheData;
}
```

`TheData` will be set by a Prism Event along with the `IsSomethingLoading` variable.

I have a call to the `GetTheData` method, but I would like it to run async (right now it just returns null if the data is not ready.  (That leads to other problems.)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In many situations like this what you need is a `TaskCompletionSource`.

You likely have a method that is able to generate the data at some point in time, but it doesn't use a task to do it.  Perhaps there is a method that takes a callback which provides the result, or an event that is fired to indicate that there is a result, or simply code using a `Thread` or `ThreadPool` that you are not inclined to re-factor into using `Task.Run`.

```
public Task<SomeData> GetTheData()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<SomeData> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<SomeData>();
    SomeObject worker = new SomeObject();
    worker.WorkCompleted += result => tcs.SetResult(result);
    worker.DoWork();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

While you may need/want to provide the `TaskCompletionSource` to the worker, or some other class, or in some other way expose it to a broader scope, I've found it's often not needed, even though it's a very powerful option when it's appropriate.

It's also possible that you can use `Task.FromAsync` to create a task based on an asynchronous operation and then either return that task directly, or `await` it in your code.

Answer (score 22):

You could use a [TaskCompletionSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) as your signal, and `await` that:

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> IsSomethingLoading = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
SomeData TheData;

public async Task<SomeData> GetTheData()
{
   await IsSomethingLoading.Task;
   return TheData;
}
```

And in your Prism event do:

```
IsSomethingLoading.SetResult(true);
```

Answer (score 6):

This work for me:

```
while (IsLoading) await Task.Delay(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool IsSomethingLoading = false
SomeData TheData;

public async Task<SomeData> GetTheData()
{
   while(IsSomethingLoading != true)
      await Task.Yield();

   return TheData;
}
```

The simplest solution

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

I propose a very simple solution but not the best to answer the original question, if you are not regarding at speed performance :

```
...
public volatile bool IsSomethingLoading = false;
...
public async Task<SomeData> GetTheData()
{
    // Launch the task asynchronously without waiting the end
    _ = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // Get the data from elsewhere ...
    });

    // Wait the flag    
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (IsSomethingLoading)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    });

   return TheData;
}
```

**Important note** : @Theodor Zoulias proposed : `IsSomethingLoading` shall be declared with `volatile` keyword, to avoid compiler optimizations and potential multithread issues when accessing from other threads.
For further information about compilator omptimizations follow this article :
[The C# Memory Model in Theory and Practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice)

I'm adding a full test code below :

**XAML :**

```
<Label x:Name="label1" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,93,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="48" Width="312"/>
```

**Test Code :**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    // volatile keyword shall be used to avoid compiler optimizations
    // and potential multithread issues when accessing IsSomethingLoading
    // from other threads.
    private volatile bool IsSomethingLoading = false;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _ = TestASyncTask();
    }

    private async Task<bool> TestASyncTask()
    {
        IsSomethingLoading = true;

        label1.Content = "Doing background task";

        // Launch the task asynchronously without waiting the end
        _ = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            IsSomethingLoading = false;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            HostController.Host.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Content = "Background task terminated"));
        });
        label1.Content = "Waiting IsSomethingLoading ...";

        // Wait the flag    
        await Task.Run(async () => { while (IsSomethingLoading) { await Task.Delay(100); }});
        label1.Content = "Wait Finished";

        return true;
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// Main UI thread host controller dispatcher
/// </summary>
public static class HostController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Main Host
    /// </summary>
    private static Dispatcher _host;
    public static Dispatcher Host
    {
        get
        {
            if (_host == null)
            {
                if (Application.Current != null)
                    _host = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
                else
                    _host = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            }

            return _host;
        }
    }
}
```